# Cannot Properly Terminate a MariaDB Session on GORM Timeout

Tags: go, mariadb, go-gorm

I have a service that is writing to MariaDB using GORM to batch insert models with a timeout of 10 seconds.

```
timeoutCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

var gorm *gorm.DB

tx := gorm.
    Session(&gorm.Session{SkipDefaultTransaction: true, Context: timeoutCtx}).
    Table(TableName("tableName")).
    Clauses(clause.OnConflict{DoNothing: true}). 
    Create(models)
if tx.Error != nil {
    return tx.Error
}
return nil
```

Every once in a while the batch inserts cause the timeout context to hit and the application connection is reused for another batch insert into the DB. However, on the DB side, the session/connection remains open for however long the actual insert takes. Each of these are taking up a connection slot while in the worst case, GORM is creating new connections to the db that also timeout and eventually all the slots are taken, locking the database.

Even with (`MaxIdleConns` + `MaxOpenConns`) * num_boxes < db_max_conections, this happens.

I am unable to reproduce this locally, but it has happened several times in our production database. I am thinking that GORM isn't terminating a session/connection properly during a session timeout. Is there a way to explicitly terminate a connection on the DB side and return it to the pool on context timeout?

Comment: To explicitly terminate a connection on the DB side and return it to the pool on context timeout is to use the `SetConnMaxLifetime` method to set a maximum amount of time a connection may be reused; to ensure that connections are returned to the pool and closed after the specified duration. You can also try setting `SetMaxIdleConns` and `SetMaxOpenConns` to limit the number of idle and open connections to the database; to help prevent connection saturation.

Comment: I don't think `SetMaxIdleConns` and `SetMaxOpenConns` will help because as I said, when  (MaxIdleConns + MaxOpenConns) * num_boxes < db_max_conections this problem still happens because this is the number of connections on the client side. There is still a leak on the db. I am thinking that setting `SetConnMaxLifetime` will have the same effect.